# LableEncoder() error (sklearn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn

How to deal with `LableEncoder()` in python 3.0 (Anaconda)? When I run my data am getting an error like `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`.

Below is the code used:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
var_mod = ['Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed',
           'Property_Area','Loan_Status']
le = LabelEncoder()
for i in var_mod:
    df[i] = le.fit_transform(df[i])
df.dtypes
```

Comment: What are the contents of `df`?

Comment: Why aren'y you just doing `le.fit_transform(var_mod)`? Also, why have you omitted critically important information from your question?

Comment: Dnt worry about it ? it public data set available for all.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try below code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le =preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(['Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed', 'Property_Area','Loan_Status'])
keys = le.classes_
values = le.transform(le.classes_)
df = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(df)
```

Comment: May be my qtn was not clear ......Here  'Gender' , 'Married' , 'Education' .. etc are columns in data set ,, Which is having different variables like 'married' and 'not married' etc ... so i want to apply lableEncoder on those columns which is going to reflect on my data set ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please post the complete stack trace of error along with the value of `i` on which its occuring. I doubt that that in that `i` column, you have different types of values.

If you can convert the data to all strings, then try this:

```
for i in var_mod:
    df[i] = le.fit_transform(df[i].astype(str))
```